# Find a successive sequence of String attributes in a Set of objects (by stream API)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have to write a method that takes a `SortedSet<MyEvent>` and a `List<String>`. It has to determine if there is a successive sequence of `MyEvent` representing the given `List<String>` by a certain class attribute.

Let's assume there was the following (code-)situation:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()
list.add("AAA");
list.add("BBB");
```

and a `Set<MyEvent>`

```
SortedSet<MyEvent> events = new TreeSet<MyEvent>();
```

with objects of type `MyEvent` which `implements Comparable<MyEvent>` (comparison by `LocalDateTime` only).
The given `List<String>` represents a sequence of abbreviations and I need to find the most recent occurrence of a sequence of `MyEvent`s whose class attributes `abbreviation` have the values of the sequence.

This is what I have done so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SortedSet<MyEvent> events = generateSomeElements();
    List<String> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
    sequence.add("AAA");
    sequence.add("BBB");

    MyEvent desired = getMostRecentLastEventOfSequence(events, sequence);

    System.out.println("Result: " + desired.toString());
}

public static MyEvent getMostRecentLastEventOfSequence(SortedSet<MyEvent> events,
                List<String> sequence) {
    // "convert" the events to a List in order to be able to access indexes
    List<MyEvent> myEvents = new ArrayList<MyEvent>();
    events.forEach(event -> myEvents.add(event));
    // provide a temporary data structure for possible results
    SortedSet<MyEvent> possibleReturnValues = new TreeSet<MyEvent>();
    // iterate the events in order to find those with a specified predecessor
    for (int i = 0; i < myEvents.size(); i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            // consider only successive elements 
            MyEvent a = myEvents.get(i - 1);
            MyEvent b = myEvents.get(i);
            // check if there is a 
            if (a.getAbbreviation().equals(sequence.get(0)) 
                && b.getAbbreviation().equals(sequence.get(1))) {
                // if a sequence was found, add the last element to the possible results
                possibleReturnValues.add(b);
            }
        }
    }

    // check if there were possible results
    if (possibleReturnValues.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        // if there are any, return the most recent / latest one
        return possibleReturnValues.stream().max(MyEvent::compareTo).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

The method is working (for this 2-element sequence, at least).

> **Is it possible to do that in a single call using the stream API (and for an unknown size of the sequence)?**

Comment: Sometimes being *Minimal* becomes a primary requirement for a question to be answered. I guess this is one of them, you can definitely get away with all those declarations and initialization and get straight to the business logic with minimal entity details and input to test.

Comment: @Naman OK, I was already thinking so, but didn't want to answer a lot of counter questions like *How does a `MyEvent` look like* and so on... Well, I will try to shorten this question.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, events.size()-1).forEach(i -> {
            MyEvent b =events.get(i + 1);
            List<String> temp = Arrays.asList(events.get(i).abbreviation, b.abbreviation);
            if (temp.equals(sequence)) {
                possibleReturnValues.add(b);
            }
        });`

Comment: @HadiJ Though your code looks kind of promising, I cannot return it because it is a `void` operation and I need to return an instance of `MyEvent`. In addition, `events` is a `SortedSet`, which means I cannot access indexes. Sorry, but these two facts in combination with no explanation make your code useless for my. Thanks anyway...

Comment: you don't need return any thing. just use my code instead of your code and other part of code is without modifying. also IMO you can use just `for` loop and for better performance add other condition too. `for (int i = 0; i < events.size() - 1; i++) {
            MyEvent b = events.get(i + 1);
            List<String> temp = Arrays.asList(events.get(i).abbreviation, b.abbreviation);
            if (temp.equals(sequence)) {
                possibleReturnValues.add(b);
            }
            if (!b.abbreviation.equals("AAA"))
                i += 1;
        }`

Comment: You have a lot of redundant operations. First, the creation of the `Map<LocalDateTime, String>`. Do you really want to eliminate events with the same creation time? Or do you only want to sort the events? And how does its key set transform from a `Set<LocalDateTime>` to a `SortedSet<MyEvent>`? Then, you don’t need to populate `possibleReturnValues` with all matching events, when all you want, is just the max value. Even worse, you are not even using the `SortedSet<MyEvent>`’s ability to return “max or null”, but doing a linear search, rendering it even more obsolete (if that’s possible).

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the suggestions. The first redundant thing (the `Map<LocalDateTime, String>`) is/was just a relic from one of my approaches that didn't lead anywhere and I have just forgotten to remove it (will do so soon). Thanks a lot for the remaining hints, too. I will take them into account.

Comment: @HadiJ I cannot use your code because it tries to access indexes of the `SortedSet<MyEvent> events`. There are no indexes to be accessed... OK, I have found out how to use it. It was `myEvents` instead of `events` to be used with indexes. Now it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task is not so hard, just create a `Stream`, apply a `filter`, and ask for the maximum value. There is the the obstacle that we need a previous element in the predicate, but we have hands on the source collection, which can provide it.

In practice, every `SortedSet` is also a `NavigableSet` which provides a [`lower`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#lower-E-) method to get the previous element, if there is one, but since your requirement is to support a `SortedSet` input, we have to provide a fall-back for the theoretical case of a `SortedSet` not being a `NavigableSet`.

Then, the operation can be implemented as

```
public static MyEvent getMostRecentLastEventOfSequence(
    SortedSet<MyEvent> events, List<String> sequence) {

    String first = sequence.get(0), second = sequence.get(1);
    UnaryOperator<MyEvent> previous;
    if (events instanceof NavigableSet) {
        NavigableSet<MyEvent> navigableSet = (NavigableSet<MyEvent>) events;
        previous = navigableSet::lower;
    }
    else previous = event -> events.headSet(event).last();

    return events.stream()
        .filter(event -> event.getAbbreviation().equals(second))
        .filter(event -> {
            MyEvent p = previous.apply(event);
            return p != null && p.getAbbreviation().equals(first);
        })
        .max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(null);
}
```

but we can do better than that. Since we now we are searching for a maximum in a *sorted* input, we know that the first match is sufficient when iterating backwards. Again, it is much smoother when the input is actually a `NavigableSet`:

```
public static MyEvent getMostRecentLastEventOfSequence(
    SortedSet<MyEvent> events, List<String> sequence) {

    String first = sequence.get(0), second = sequence.get(1);
    UnaryOperator<MyEvent> previous;
    Stream<MyEvent> stream;
    if (events instanceof NavigableSet) {
        NavigableSet<MyEvent> navigableSet = (NavigableSet<MyEvent>) events;
        previous = navigableSet::lower;
        stream = navigableSet.descendingSet().stream();
    }
    else {
        previous = event -> events.headSet(event).last();
        stream = Stream.iterate(events.last(), previous).limit(events.size());
    }

    return stream
        .filter(event -> event.getAbbreviation().equals(second))
        .filter(event -> {
            MyEvent p = previous.apply(event);
            return p != null && p.getAbbreviation().equals(first);
        })
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

So this method will search backwards and stop at the first match, which will already be the maximum element, without the need to traverse all elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations and the two methods. May I assume there is no possibility of using a *one-line* or *one-statement* stream api call? I was expecting that, but thought it might be possible. The `NavigableSet` is a really useful hint because I can store the elements in such a set before applying the method.

Comment: As said, most `SortedSet` implementations *are* already a `NavigableSet`. This includes typical implementations as `TreeSet` and the key set of a `TreeMap`. The operation actually *is* a single Stream statement. I only extracted `first` and `second` for readability and to avoid repeated executions of `sequence.get(0)` and `sequence.get(1)`. Similarly, the test whether the set is a `NavigableSet` could have done inside the function itself, but it would not add to readability nor performance. Letting these preparations aside, there is only the one Stream operation at the end.

Comment: OK, thanks, that answers everything (and raises some questions about my understanding of *a single stream operation*). This is what I wanted.

Comment: You can see it this way: in the second example, `findFirst()` is the only method invocation doing actual data processing.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using index. The size of sequence won't be limited to 2.

```
public static MyEvent getMostRecentLastEventOfSequence(SortedSet<MyEvent> events, List<String> sequence) {
  final List<MyEvent> eventList = new ArrayList<>(events);
  Collections.reverse(eventList);
  final int seqLength = sequence.size();

  OptionalInt first = IntStream.range(0, eventList.size() - seqLength + 1)
      .filter(i -> IntStream.range(0, seqLength)
          .allMatch(j -> eventList.get(i + j).getAbbreviation().equals(sequence.get(seqLength - j - 1))))
      .findFirst();

  return first.isPresent() ? eventList.get(first.getAsInt()) : null;
}
```

Here is sample test code:

```
@Test
void test_56005015() throws Exception {
  List<String> sequence = Arrays.asList("AAA", "BBB", "CCC");

  SortedSet<MyEvent> events = new TreeSet<>();
  events.add(new MyEvent("AAA", LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1)));
  events.add(new MyEvent("BBB", LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(2)));
  events.add(new MyEvent("CCC", LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(3)));
  events.add(new MyEvent("AAA", LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(4)));
  events.add(new MyEvent("BBB", LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(5)));
  events.add(new MyEvent("CCC", LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(6)));

  MyEvent result = getMostRecentLastEventOfSequence(events, sequence);
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

with `MyEvent` class annotated with `Lombok`.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public static class MyEvent implements Comparable<MyEvent> {
  private String abbreviation;
  private LocalDateTime eventTime;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MyEvent o) {
    return eventTime.compareTo(o.eventTime);
  }
}
```